# time/date calculation

Tags: php, mysql, sql, time

First, an entry in the database:

[image]

I have an input form that writes start date, start and end times (in hour and minute) of working days plus lunch break in minutes (in the example dato=date, modetime=start hour, modeminut=start minute, fyrtime=end hour, fyrminut=end minute). I need to do several calculations:

- First calculate the date, start hour and minute into the datetime field modetid.
- The do a similar calculation with the end hours and minutes, but move the date up one day if end hours is less than start hour (lets call it fyrtid)
- And finally calculate the difference between fyrtid and modetid minus the pause minutes.

Can it be done directly and automatically in the database (if yes, how) or do I need some PHP to do it (and again, if yes, how)?

I know its a tall order but I have not been able to find much information on date/time calculations that made much sense on my low level of knowledge. Any link to a comprehensive guide on date/time calculation in MySQL or PHP would also be greatly welcomed.

Comment: It is the **EASIEST** query ever. Do you know *anything* about sql?

Comment: Btw, what is the `id` column in the desired result?

Comment: Then show me how it is done

Comment: "then show" doesn't work here. What have you tried? What actually you don't understand?

Answer (score 1):

its easy

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `date` >= CURDATE() ;
```

Comment: Not sure why you used `LIMIT` here, but apart of that it's correct

Comment: because he want upcoming date not dates.

Comment: have you checked the "Desire result" in the question?

Comment: @user2092317: please see the OP's desired output!

Comment: It is giving me an empty results

Comment: LOL, OP stores dates as strings `'Oct 22 2014'`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE NOW() < `date`
```